# [ERROR KubeletVersion]: the kubelet version is higher than the control plane version

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to kubernetes and I'm setting up my first testing cluster.  However, I'll get this error when I set up the master node.  But I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
[ERROR KubeletVersion]: the kubelet version is higher than the control plane version.
This is not a supported version skew and may lead to a malfunctional cluster.
Kubelet version: "1.12.0-rc.1" Control plane version: "1.11.3"
```

The host is fully patched to the latest levels

CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

Many Thanks
S

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same problem and used the kubeadm option: --kubernetes-version=v1.12.0-rc.1

> sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.16.0.0/12 --kubernetes-version=v1.12.0-rc.1

I'm using a JVM image that was prepared a few weeks ago and have just updated the packages. Kubeadm, kubectl and kubelet all now return version v1.12.0-rc.1 when asked but when 'kubeadm init' is called it kicks off with the previous version.

> [init] using Kubernetes version: v1.11.3

specifying the (control plane) version did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after doing that do you have any problems with the master node? If I do a `kubectl get nodes` I get `xxx-xxx-xxx   NotReady   master   87m   v1.12.0-rc.1` . And if I do a describe to that node the last message says: `Ready            False   Fri, 21 Sep 2018 18:19:19 +0000   Fri, 21 Sep 2018 16:49:38 +0000   KubeletNotReady              runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized`

Comment: After init, the nodes do not come up. There is a problem with kube-proxy (neworking) due to access to /proc/sys/... (try "kubectl logs pod kube-proxy-xxxxx -n kube-system). Seems this got into the wild (linux packages): https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68504 . I'm going to try going back to 1.11.

Answer (score 2):

Install the same version of kubelet & kubeadm

```
yum -y remove kubelet
yum -y install kubelet-1.11.3-0 kubeadm-1.11.3-0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error on a clean Centos 7 install after fully updating with `yum update`, and then applying the instructions from https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/ for setup.

Adding the option for `--ignore-preflight-errors=KubeletVersion` allows the installer to continue but the installation is non-working afterwards.

I was able to remove everything and reinstall matching versions with the following:

`yum -y remove kubelet kubeadm kubectl
yum install -y --disableexcludes=kubernetes kubeadm-1.11.3-0.x86_64 kubectl-1.11.3-0.x86_64 kubelet-1.11.3-0.x86_64`